# Is it possible to upgrade Bind + OpenSSH in centos 7?

Tags: linux, server, centos, centos7

I'm trying to update Bind + OpenSSH on my server

**named -v**

### [image]

**ssh -V**

[image]

---

**When I run :**

Bind :

```
wget http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.11.1rc3/bind-9.11.1rc3.tar.gz
tar -xzf bind-9.11.1rc3.tar.gz
cd bind-9.11.1rc3
./configure
make
make install
service named restart
```

OpenSSH :

```
cd /usr/src 
wget http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.5p1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssh-7.5p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.5p1
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh  --without-zlib-version-check 
make 
make install 
service sshd restart
```

**Result :**

it's the same :

[image]

[image]

> yum update not working

**I run :**

```
yum clean all
```

But it's the same Result .

---

**/usr/bin/ssh -V**

[image]

Comment: check with full path /usr/bin/ssh -v ??

Comment: Ok Sir @rups , i checked .

Comment: sorry check with this /usr/bin/ssh -V

Comment: Ok , Sir .. @rups , i checked with /usr/bin/ssh -V

Comment: is it expected one ?

Comment: it's the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144800/discussion-between-rups-and-moon93).